# sql update based on column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I have a problem.

I have `T1`, `T2`, `T_Join` tables.

`T_Join`: first column: `ID` (unique) e.g.: 10,11,12,13. Second column: `CODE`, it contains attributes which are equals to the column names of `T2`. E.g.: type, source, section, importance. These are identified by the `ID` in the `T1`. According to this, the ID of attribute 'source' is 11.

```
ID  CODE
10  type
11  source
12  section
13  importance
```

In table `T1`, the first column is the `data_ID` which is not unique:  1020, 1020, 1020, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1023, 1023, 1028, 1028, 1028, 1035, 1035, etc.

The second column is ID from `T_Join`. At this example 4 ID can belong to 1 `data_ID`, these declare, of which value appears in the third column (VALUE):

```
data_ID  ID  VALUE  
1020     10  1
1020     11  123
1020     12  9
1020     13  4
1022     10  2
1022     12  15
1023     10  2
1023     11  108
1023     13  2
1028     12  20
```

...

It means the item with ID 1020 is type 1, originates from source No.123, the real object which identified by this ID stored in the section 9 and has a 4th level importance.

Now, I have a table T2. The first column is the same data_ID as in T1. In this table these are unique. The other columns: (how surprising!) type, source, section, importance. (In reality, there are not only four attributes, but at least fifty!)
So the table looks something like this:

```
data_ID  type  source  section  importance
1020     1     123     9        2
1022     1     95      3        5
1023     2     108     21       4
1028     1     147     17       5
```

The T2 contains the newer data. I would like to update the T1.VALUE column with these. Following my examples above, The updated T1 should look like this:

```
data_ID  ID  VALUE  
1020     10  1
1020     11  123
1020     12  9
1020     13  2
1022     10  1
1022     12  3
1023     10  2
1023     11  108
1023     13  4
1028     12  17
...
```

So, at data_ID 1020, the importance was 4 and it turned to 2 because in the T1 the ID is 13 and it refers to attribute 'importance' from T_Join table and so on.
I would like to update all the data in this way. I'm not an SQL expert and I've managed to create this code:

```
update T1 set VALUE = 
(select * from T2 
 inner join T_Join on ID=
(SELECT 
    c.name 
FROM
    sys.objects o
INNER JOIN
    sys.columns c
ON
    c.object_id = o.object_id
AND o.name = 'T2') 
where T1.data_ID = T2.data_ID and T2.ID = T_Join.ID)

from T1
inner join T2 on T1.data_ID = T2.data_ID
inner join T_Join on T1.ID = T_Join.ID

select * from T1
```

but it doesn't work, the error message:

> *Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*

I tried to solve it with CURSOR statement and declared variables (based on an advice) but it doesn't work either.

Please, if somebody has an idea how i could solve this (in the simplest way), answer as detailed as possible.

Comment: +1 You included a lot of details about the issue that you are having and even showed what you tried to fix it. This is a good first post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current design is you have one table that is normalized and one that is de-normalized and you need to perform an update.

You first, will want to de-normalize the `T2` table, which will take the columns and convert it into rows.  In SQL Server 2005+, they introduced the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function which will perform this for you.

The first step is to `SELECT` the data from `T2` and `T_Join` into rows.  The `SELECT` statement is:

```
select j.id,
  j.code,
  u.data_id,
  u.value
from T_Join j
inner join
(
  select data_id, col, value
  from T2
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (type, source, section, importance)
  ) unpiv
) u
  on j.code = u.col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2407/11). This takes your column data and converts it to rows giving the result:

```
| ID |       CODE | DATA_ID | VALUE |
-------------------------------------
| 10 |       type |    1020 |     1 |
| 11 |     source |    1020 |   123 |
| 12 |    section |    1020 |     9 |
| 13 | importance |    1020 |     2 |
| 10 |       type |    1022 |     1 |
| 11 |     source |    1022 |    95 |
| 12 |    section |    1022 |     3 |
| 13 | importance |    1022 |     5 |
| 10 |       type |    1023 |     2 |
| 11 |     source |    1023 |   108 |
| 12 |    section |    1023 |    21 |
| 13 | importance |    1023 |     4 |
| 10 |       type |    1028 |     1 |
| 11 |     source |    1028 |   147 |
| 12 |    section |    1028 |    17 |
| 13 | importance |    1028 |     5 |
```

Once the data is in that format, you can use it in an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update t1
set t1.value = t.value
from t1
inner join
(
  select j.id,
    j.code,
    u.data_id,
    u.value
  from T_Join j
  inner join
  (
    select data_id, col, value
    from T2
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for col in (type, source, section, importance)
    ) unpiv
  ) u
    on j.code = u.col
) t
  on t1.data_id = t.data_id
  and t1.id = t.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2407/8).

The next problem that you stated you have is that there are about 50 columns that you need to *unpivot*. If that is the case, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the list of columns to turn into rows. You dynamic SQL script will be:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('T2') and
               C.name not in ('data_ID')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'update t1
     set t1.value = t.value
     from t1
     inner join
     (
       select j.id,
         j.code,
         u.data_id,
         u.value
       from T_Join j
       inner join
       (
         select data_id, col, value
         from T2
         unpivot
         (
           value
           for col in ('+@colsUnpivot+')
         ) unpiv
       ) u
         on j.code = u.col
     ) t
       on t1.data_id = t.data_id
       and t1.id = t.id;'

exec(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2407/10).

The code will update `T1` with the following result:

```
| DATA_ID | ID | VALUE |
------------------------
|    1020 | 10 |     1 |
|    1020 | 11 |   123 |
|    1020 | 12 |     9 |
|    1020 | 13 |     2 |
|    1022 | 10 |     1 |
|    1022 | 12 |     3 |
|    1023 | 10 |     2 |
|    1023 | 11 |   108 |
|    1023 | 13 |     4 |
|    1028 | 12 |    17 |
```